# Linux Live, getting stuck when visiting website using firefox

Tags: linux, firefox

Im using linux live to test few things ,
installing few apps to see everything is ok,
so im doing the research also in this Virtual Box,
after using the firefox for few mins its slow down the machine or stucking it ,
what could i config before so it will run better

thx

more memory ?

Comment: How much memory have you allocated the virtual machine? If you only gave it 1 vcpu and 2 GB of memory what kind of performance do you expect?

Comment: what live image are you using? Is it one website or all of them that this is happening with? Have you tested with other browsers besides Firefox? How much memory does your VM have?

Comment: @kemotep 2gb and 8 cores zorin os and mx linux

Comment: @Kefka  zorin os and mx linux

Comment: @RMat What is your cpu?

Comment: @kemotep its not my cpu

Comment: @RMat I was just trying to figure out what the bottleneck could be. However it is likely the ram. 2 GB of ram is not a lot compared to that many threads. Modern websites target the most common hardware configuration, which including mobile phones, has more and more memory every year. 2 GB of ram might not cut it to browse the internet these days without blocking javascript, etc. I mention the cpu because you may be over provisioning the threads leading to reduced performance or increased latency.